# Delete item in a list using a for-loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, collections

I have an array with subjects and every subject has connected time. I want to compare every subjects in the list. If there are two of the same subjects, I want to add the times of both subjects, and also want to delete the second subject information (subject-name and time).

But If I delete the item, the list become shorter, and I get an out-of-range-error. I tried to make the list shorter with using subjectlegth-1, but this also don't work.

```
   ...
   subjectlegth = 8
   for x in range(subjectlength):
        for y in range(subjectlength):
            if subject[x] == subject[y]:
                if x != y:
                    #add
                    time[x] = time[x] + time[y]
                    #delete
                    del time[y]
                    del subject[y]
                    subjectlength = subjectlength - 1
```

Comment: have a look at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterate backwards, if you can:

```
for x in range(subjectlength - 1, -1, -1):
```

and similarly for `y`.

Comment: While this "solves" your problem of how to delete elements of a list while iterating over it, your bigger problem is that you are in fact modifying a list while iterating over it.  Whenever you are considering doing this, step back and see if you can readdress the problem by constructing a new list with the desired values.  In this case, you are gathering together time values for like subjects - think "dict", which is a much better structure for this. If using Python 2.5 or later, think "defaultdict", which is even easier to use than dict.get(). Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' answer is the right one.

Answer (score 8):

If the elements of `subject` are hashable:

```
finalinfo = {}

for s, t in zip(subject, time):
  finalinfo[s] = finalinfo.get(s, 0) + t
```

This will result in a dict with `subject: time` key-value pairs.

Answer (score 6):

The best practice is to make a new list of the entries to delete, and to delete them after walking the list:

```
to_del = []
subjectlength = 8
for x in range(subjectlength):
    for y in range(x):
        if subject[x] == subject[y]:
            #add
            time[x] = time[x] + time[y]
            to_del.append(y)

to_del.reverse()
for d in to_del:
    del subject[d]
    del time[d]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way would be to create the subject and time lists anew, using a dict to sum up the times of recurring subjects (I am assuming subjects are strings i.e. hashable).

```
subjects=['math','english','necromancy','philosophy','english','latin','physics','latin']
time=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
tuples=zip(subjects,time)
my_dict={}
for subject,t in tuples:
    try:
        my_dict[subject]+=t
    except KeyError:
        my_dict[subject]=t
subjects,time=my_dict.keys(), my_dict.values()
print subjects,time
```

Comment: Learn about dict.get() or even better, collections.defaultdict.  Much cleaner than try-except KeyError.  And why print out keys() and values()?  What about items()?

Comment: I know about get and defaultdict, but wasn't sure if the OP was so I stuck with an approach that assumes less knowledge. As for keys() and values(), the OP wants two separate lists and items() returns a list of (key,value) tuples.

Comment: @MAK - Fair enough, insofar as you are perturbing the OP's original design as little as possible. But a program that keeps matched data values in separate lists *really* should be redone to use a dict. What if the design calls for adding an instructor, or a room number? Should these be added by tacking on more order-sensitive lists? You do the OP a disservice by assuming that dict concepts are beyond him/her.

Comment: @Paul McGuire: Those are things you should be saying to the OP, not me. I am not assuming dict concepts are beyond him, I am guarding against the possibility that he might not be familiar enough with dicts yet.

Answer (score 0):

Though a `while` loop is certainly a better choice for this, if you insist on using a `for` loop, one can replace the `list` elements-to-be-deleted with None, or any other distinguishable item, and redefine the `list` after the `for` loop. The following code removes even elements from a list of integers:

```
nums = [1, 1, 5, 2, 10, 4, 4, 9, 3, 9]
for i in range(len(nums)):
  # select the item that satisfies the condition
  if nums[i] % 2 == 0:
    # do_something_with_the(item)
    nums[i] = None  # Not needed anymore, so set it to None
# redefine the list and exclude the None items
nums = [item for item in nums if item is not None]
# num = [1, 1, 5, 9, 3, 9]
```

In the case of the question in this post:

```
...
for i in range(subjectlength - 1):
  for j in range(i+1, subjectlength):
    if subject[i] == subject[j]:
      #add
      time[i] += time[j]
        # set to None instead of delete
        time[j] = None
        subject[j] = None
time = [item for item in time if item is not None]
subject = [item for item in subject if item is not None]
```